# WordPress last_modified what was changed

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to find out if only the date/time of a post has been changed or something in the content? The the_modified_date() function covers both and I can't find a way to do a specific check.

The Background: I have a list of posts which will be published in the future and I want to have some feedback for the users if the date or time of an upcoming post changes.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
$loop_ls = new WP_Query( $args_ls );
if($loop_ls->have_posts()) : while($loop_ls->have_posts()) : $loop_ls->the_post();
    // set date/time variables
    $live_date = get_the_date('j.n.');
    $live_time = get_the_date('H:i');
?>

    <?php if ( get_post_status() == 'future' ) : ?>
    <div class="live live--upcoming">
        <p><?php _e('Am', 'textdomain') ?> <span class="post-date"><?php echo $live_date; ?></span> <?php _e('um', 'textdomain') ?> <span class="post-time"><?php echo $live_time; ?></span> <?php _e('Uhr', 'textdomain') ?> <?php _e('zum Thema:', 'textdomain') ?>
            <br/><span class="post-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php elseif ( get_post_status() == 'publish' ) : ?>
    <div class="live live--now">
        <p><?php _e('Jetzt:', 'textdomain') ?> <span class="post-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></span></p>
        <a class="btn btn--default" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('zum LIVE Video', 'textdomain') ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show a minimal code sample to reproduce the issue you are having?

Comment: I added my code to the initial question. I tried to compare the post_date() with the_modified_date() but it seems like the post date is not the creation date but the publish date (in the future) and the modified date is the date I save the post. But modified date changes every time a change/save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out a way to save a creation date for posts published in the future (code below). But I still have the problem, that I can't check if only a posts date/time is modified (not the content).

```
function wx_add_creation_date_to_live_videos( $post ) {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if( $post_type == 'video' && has_term('live', 'video_category') ) {
        // If this is a revision, do nothing.
        if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
            return;

        $creation_date = get_the_modified_date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_id);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'creation_date', $creation_date );
    }
}
add_action( 'draft_to_future', 'wx_add_creation_date_to_live_videos', 10, 3 );
```

EDIT: 
sometimes you just think too complicated. To check a change on post date/time I changed the code above to this

```
$orig_publish_date = get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_id);
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'orig_publish_date', $orig_publish_date );
```

And now I can compare the values of the orig_publish_date with the current publish_date. And that's it.